# Survey - DF1 - Questions are in Row1, In DF2 all questions are listed in the first column Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

Please if you can help me with this,

Dataframe 1
[image: This is first data frame, where questions are in row 0]

Dataframe 2
[image: This is dataframe 2, where questions are in a column]

I want to calculate Number of Yes from DF1 to Df2

Something like this

```
 for x in DF2['Questions']:
    if x == first row of DF1 count 'Yes'
```

and it goes through the whole row and where the condition is met, it counts yes and posts in a Dataframe2['Yes']

I have been trying to do this but none of what i did work. Please if you can help me or suggest what should i look at.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df_ = df[['Q1', 'Q2']].eq('Yes').sum(axis=0).to_frame(name='Yes').rename_axis('Questions').reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

  Questions  Yes
0        Q1    1
1        Q2    0
```

To illustrate step by step:

First you can use `df[['Q1', 'Q2']].eq('Yes')` to get a boolean dataframe which tells if the value is `Yes`

```
      Q1     Q2
0   True  False
1  False  False
```

Then you can sum this boolean dataframe by row with `.sum(axis=0)`

```
Q1    1
Q2    0
dtype: int64
```

At last, you can reset the Series to dataframe with `.to_frame(name='Yes')`, rename the index with `.rename_axis('Questions')` and reset it back to column with `.reset_index()`

```
  Questions  Yes
0        Q1    1
1        Q2    0
```

Comment: Thank you @Ynjxsjmh - I am getting Value Error - ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: @Mob If you do it step by step as I said, which step gives you this error.

Comment: First step, ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 27, placement implies 1

Comment: Sorry it is sorted, I was adding a column  e.g. where you said df_ , i was doing df_['Yes'] as soon as i removed that, it worked, Ynjxsjmh i really appreciate your time and patience, Thank you very much for all your help. Thank you